# Can an electrolytic capacitor discharge through its top?

Tags: capacitor, discharge

Can an electrolytic capacitor discharge through its top?

Is it potentially dangerous to touch a large electrolytic capacitor on the top if fully charged?

Comment: Grab a multimeter, probe the top with respect to something. Do you see any voltage?

Comment: If it is a high voltage capacitor, and it is charged, you should not touch the terminals. It could be painful, or in worst case scenario, it could kill you.

Comment: discharge WHAT through its top? Electricity : no. Smoke, paper, foil and electrolyte, yes.

Comment: There can be no single correct answer as **it depends**. On some capacitors the metal top is connected to one of its pins, then depending on the circuit and device, that pin could be grounded (and probably safe to touch) but it could also have a **lethal** voltage on it. In general: you should not touch **ANY** electrical component unless you **KNOW** it is safe to do so. Experienced engineers would only touch a capacitor when they know it is discharged and/or are 100% sure it is charged with a low voltage and the circuit isn't live. Be safe and when in doubt: don't touch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In all cases that I'm familiar with, the case of an Aluminum electrolytic capacitor is connected to the (-) lead on the part.  In cases like axial-leaded devices this is often obvious as you can see the lead connected to the case at the end.

With radial-leaded devices this may be less obvious but it's almost certainly connected.

That's one reason for the shrink-wrapped plastic covering that covers these devices.

For low-voltage circuits you would be relatively safe to touch this as it's usually GROUND but in other devices with HV, you should exercise caution.  It may be grounded but it doesn't have to be.

Comment: I think your last sentence is the most important one. If a circuit has, say, +/-100V supplies then the case of the capacitor could be at -100V with respect to ground.

Comment: It should also be noted that the top of radial electrolytic capacitors is scored,  In the event of a blowout the top of the capacitor unfolds.  The whole outside case, including the folding pieces are electrically connected.  To prevent making electrical contact during a blowout one must always put adequate spacing between the top of the part and any metal enclosure.

Answer (score 0):

It might only be safe in low-voltage such as motherboards.

Bipolar supplies use the lid V- as the negative voltage.

I recently found a non isolated ACDC converter for a 100W fan that used single supply -70V relative to Earth ground. (not safe to touch)  Positive was not Earth ground but rather somewhere with diode drop and +5V. ( for some reason unknown to drive 3pH BLDC FETs)